# Collection View Item clicked when selected

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

For now, I have this:

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        print(indexPaths)
        }
    }
```

and it works when the item was not already selected. I'm looking for some way to catch when an item already selected was clicked. For example:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, didClickItemsAt indexPaths: Set<IndexPath>) {
        ...
    }
```

EDIT: didDeselectItems doesn't fire by clicking on selected items

Comment: didDeSelect ???

Comment: idk why but didDeselectItems doesn't fire by clicking on selected items